# FatalExecutionEngineError during navigation and collection methods

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, mvvm-light

This is probably an mvvm-light question more than a winrt question, but I have an app that uses mvvm-light and SQLite written in C#.  It is a TV show library app that displays all of your series on the main page.  You can then drill down through the episodes you own and more.  In any case, I use the mvvm-light messenger to send data from the series library page's view model to the episodes page's view model.  I populate an ObservableCollection<object> collection called CombinedVMs using SQLite upon receipt of the message.

The trouble is that there seems to be a truly random error that I get doing this navigation.  The error is a code 80131544 and I can't get any other information from the debugger because "a native frame is on top of the call stack".  The error always seems to stop at my CombinedVMs collection, usually when I try to add to it.  Sometimes, the error happens when I hit the back button and a method gets called where the CombinedVMs collection gets cleared.  I can sometimes navigate back and forth between series many times... sometimes I can do it just twice before it hits the error.

This only started happening to me when I changed my code from using a grouped GridView control on the episodes view to a non-grouped GridView that uses an ItemTemplateSelector to differentiate between season headers and the episodes.  I use CombinedVMs (ObservableCollection<object>) to hold both SeasonItemViewModels and EpisodeItemViewModels.

I'm wondering if this has to due with how I've setup the mvvm-light portion of the code.  The following is exactly how I do my navigation.

```
public RelayCommand GoToSeriesCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _gotoSeriesCommand ?? (_gotoSeriesCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
              {
                  SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<SeriesViewModel>();
                  Messenger.Default.Send<NavigateToSeriesViewMessage>(new NavigateToSeriesViewMessage() 
                  { 
                      FolderGuid = this.FolderGuid,
                      DisplayName = this.DisplayName,
                      FanartPathList = this.FanartPathList,
                      SeriesId = this.SeriesId
                  });
                  MainViewModel._navigationService.Navigate(typeof(SeriesView));
              }));
    }
}
```

My ViewModelLocator has this in it that is related:

```
static ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, DesignNavigationService>();
    }
    else
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => new NavigationService());
    }

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SeriesViewModel>();

}

public SeriesViewModel SeriesVM
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SeriesViewModel>();
    }
}

static public SeriesViewModel SeriesVMStatic
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SeriesViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Anyways, I am stumped.  I have no idea how to proceed.  There is a topic on the microsoft forum about this particular error code, but it's from last year and there's a claim that it's been fixed from an update.

Can I provide anything else?  I don't know where to go from here....  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had one of these a while ago.  They occur if you've got unmanaged resources in use and they're not cleaned up properly.  You might find that the SQLLite DB is using unmanaged code.  I'd suggest you go through and ensure you're disposing of all your SQLLite instances after use.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't realize I had an answer.  Sorry for not giving credit earlier.  In fact, I can barely remember this problem.  :(  
I did have many problems with using SQLite... especially trying their async code.  Ended up changing everything to synchronous.